# PHP isn't updating values in an SQL row

Tags: php, sql

I made a comment page to display comments that hadn't been approved by any Admins yet. On this page there is a button where you click approve to goto a seperate PHP file that will approve the comment you selected. The comment isn't being approved in my DB and the $SearchQueryParameter isn't even being displayed in my toast. It does however give me a success toast.

This is the approval file.

```
    <!-- check DB File-->
<?php require_once("includes/DB.php"); ?>
    <!-- check functions/errors File-->
<?php require_once("includes/functions.php"); ?>
    <!-- check sessions File-->
<?php require_once("includes/sessions.php"); ?>

<?php 
    if(isset($_GET["id"])&&!empty($_GET["id"])){
        $SearchQueryParameter = $_Get["id"];
        global $ConnectingDB;
        $Admin = $_SESSION["Username"];
        $sql = "UPDATE comments 
        SET  approvedby='$Admin', cmntstatus='ON'
        WHERE id='$SearchQueryParameter'";
        $Execute = $ConnectingDB->query($sql);
        if ($Execute){
            $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]="Comment ".$SearchQueryParameter." Approved Successfully";
            Redirect_to("Comments.php");
        }else {
            $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]="There was an error!";
            Redirect_to("Comments.php");
        }
    }
?>
```

Here is the comment file, It seems to be working fine as a whole. There is more but I think it's irrelevant.

```
<table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
                        <thead class="table-dark">
                            <tr>
                                <th>#</th>
                                <th>Date&Time</th>
                                <th>Author</th>
                                <th>Comments</th>
                                <th>Approve</th>
                                <th>Delete</th>
                                <th>ID</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
              <?php
                 global $ConnectingDB;
                 $sql = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE cmntstatus='OFF'
                 ORDER BY id desc";
                 $stmt = $ConnectingDB->query($sql);
                 $Sr = 0;
                 while ($DataRows = $stmt->fetch()){
                       $CmntId     =   $DataRows["id"];
                       $DateTime   =   $DataRows["datetime"];
                       $CmntName   =   $DataRows["name"];
                       $Cmnt       =   $DataRows["comment"];
                       $Sr++;
                   if(strlen($CmntName)>10) {
                     $CmntName = substr($CmntName,0,10)."...";
                   }
                   if(strlen($DateTime)>10){
                      $DateTime = substr($DateTime,0,10)."...";
                   }
              ?>
                        <tbody>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo htmlentities($Sr);?></td>
                                <td><?php echo htmlentities($DateTime); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo htmlentities($CmntName); ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo htmlentities($Cmnt); ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="ApproveComment.php?id=<?php echo $CmntId?>" class="btn btn-success">Approve</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <a href="DeleteComment.php?id=<?php echo $CmntId?>" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a>
                                </td>
                                <td>
                                    <?php echo htmlentities($CmntId); ?>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
            <?php 
              }?>
```

Comment: I’m not sure but I seem to recall that the superglobals in PHP are case-sensitive. Have you tried using `$_GET["id"]` instead of `$_Get["id"]`?

Comment: That was the problem! Thanks so much.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not sure but I seem to recall that the superglobals in PHP are case-sensitive. Have you tried using $_GET["id"] instead of $_Get["id"]? –
rickdenhaan
6 mins ago

^ That fixed it ^